# Searching through a linked list for value closest to a set value

Tags: c, function

So I have a function that searches a linked list, and finds the value closest to a number within the linked list. During this process it should print every value it finds that's the new closest value.

```
void search(struct Node* head, double x, FILE* fp) {

    double temp = 99999; 
    double calc = fabs(head->data - x);

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (calc <= temp) {
            fprintf(fp, "%.6f,", head->data);
            temp = calc;
            head = head-> next;
        }
        head = head->next;
        calc = fabs(head->data - x);
    }
}
```

Linked list node structure:

```
struct Node
{
  double data;
  struct Node *next;
};
```

`double x` is just the value I'm looking for and `FILE * fp` is the CSV file I'm writing to.

It won't print anything to the CSV file, not sure what the issue with the algorithm is. I'm getting process terminated with status -1073741819.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't print to my CSV at all

Comment: So, you have a problem with the algorithem ? Or with writing to CSV file ?

Comment: The algorithm, writing to the CSV file in other functions is fine.

Comment: You said "it doesn't print to my CSV at all", then "writing to the CSV file in other functions is fine". I assume then that your problem is **not** with the algorithm, but with writing to the CSV file within that specific function, which you call "the algorithm". Am I correct?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your loop. How often do you assign to `head` in the loop? And what happens if `head` becomes a null pointer and you then calculate the value for `calc`?

Comment: You skip values. Remove this line from inside the `if` block:  `head = head-> next;`

Comment: I'm getting process terminated with status -1073741819. Alright I'll try that @KlasLindbäck

Comment: You have `head = head->next;` twice, this is plain  wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a [MCVE] with an example of input and expected output.

Comment: A simple `for()` loop instead of the `while()` loop could simplify the logic. (and make the error more visible)

Comment: That final `calc = fabs(head->data - x);` will give you UB when you've reached the end of the list. It should be at the start of the loop's body.

Comment: That was it @unwind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're skipping over nodes and computing values without checking for null pointers.

Here's your code with a comment in every place where `head` could be null and it would be a problem:

```
void search(struct Node* head, double x, FILE* fp) {

    double temp = 99999; 
    // head could be null here...
    double calc = fabs(head->data - x);

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (calc <= temp) {
            fprintf(fp, "%.6f,", head->data);
            temp = calc;
            head = head-> next;
        }
        // head could also be null here, because of the conditional above...
        head = head->next;
        // and head could also be null here, because of the line above.
        calc = fabs(head->data - x);
    }
}
```

Instead, start at the beginning and as long as `head` isn't null:

- Compute the difference between `head`'s value and `x`
- If it's smaller than your previous value, print it and save it for later
- Continue to the next node

In C:

```
void search(struct Node* head, double x, FILE* fp) {
    double temp = 99999; 
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        double calc = fabs(head->data - x);
        if (calc <= temp) {
            fprintf(fp, "%.6f,", head->data);
            temp = calc;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure the file is opened correctly and once the algorithm is done the file is closed. You also advance your list twice, once if the `if` is true, and again after the if-block.

```
void example(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    if (!(fp=fopen(myfile.csv", "w")) return(0);
    search(head, 123.0, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and:

```
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        double calc = fabs(head->data - x);
        if (calc <= temp) {
            fprintf(fp, "%.6f,", head->data);
            temp = calc;
            //head = head-> next;  // remove this line
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
```

As molbdnilo points out in his answer, after advancing head it could have become null and the calculation should be moved to the top of the loop. (I have added that to make this answer correct.)

Comment: Just add calc = fabs(head->data - x); above the if loop and that's the answer.